# Oracle ODI 12c performance tuning how to add hint

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlperformance, oracle-data-integrator

In Oracle Data Integrator 12c I have a job that's selecting from quite few number of tables and writing to a file. As suggested by DBA he wanted me to add HINT at the begining of the select query ex:

```
SELECT
   a.fname,
   a.lname,
   l.abc
FROM
   customers  a,
   location   l,
   region     r
WHERE
 a.xyz =l.xyz and
     l.coloumn = r.coloumn and
       a.id = 1243
   AND b.city = 'new york' ....
```

the above needs to be changed to

```
SELECT
    /*+ leading (a) */ a.fname,
    a.lname,
    l.abc
FROM
    customers  a,
    location   l,
    region     r
WHERE
      a.xyz =l.xyz and
      l.coloumn = r.coloumn and 
        a.id = 1243
    AND b.city = 'new york'....
```

how to achieve this in ODI and where can I observer the change.

Thank you all

Comment: It's not clear how you want to join the tables. Please use modern join syntax, instead of the comma-separated list of tables from 1989.

Comment: Obviously if the query is generated by `ODI` you must use some feature of `ODI` to add the hints. Google for "add hint Oracle ODI" returns results, did you check them? You may also search in the documentation for a *check box* `use ANSI join syntax` so that @TheImpaler will be satisfied.